# Discord.py bot.get_context() does not return ctx object

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I wanted to run command from on_message(), but bot.get_context() return coroutine object, not context.
Error that code gives: await bot.get_context(message).invoke(bot.get_command("do_something"))
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'invoke'

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
bot_token = ""
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("!"))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #print(type(bot.get_context(message)))
    if message.content == "do something":
        await bot.get_context(message).invoke(bot.get_command("do_something"))
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def do_something(ctx):
    #print(type(ctx))
    await ctx.send("Working")

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `.invoke()` on the coroutine object, rather than the final returned object (the context).

Either store the context in a variable and then call invoke on it:

```py
ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
ctx.invoke...
```

Or, and this is something I haven't tried and don't actually know if it works (but it might!), try this:

```py
(await bot.get_context(message)).invoke...
```